# PHP and Absolute paths, but it was working a second ago

Tags: php, absolute-path

I don't see the error..

I have an index file under the web root. Index file sets an array with basic paths, like so:

```
$medium    = 'web';
$framework = '_magma';
$js_lib    = '_lava';
$path_info = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$base_path = $path_info['dirname'];
print_r($base_path);

$paths = ['root'      => $base_path,
          'framework' => $framework,
          'js_lib'    => $js_lib,
          'medium'    => '/' . $medium,
          'uri'       => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']];

try {
    if (!include($paths['root'] . $paths['framework'] . '/core/AutoLoader.php')) {
        throw new Exception ('<b>Error - AutoLoader is missing</b>');
    }
    $loader   = new AutoLoader($paths);
    $appStack = new BootStrap($paths);
    $app      = new StartPage($paths, $appStack->getConfig());
    $app->start();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo
        '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
        . $e->getMessage()
        . '<br />File: '
        . $e->getFile()
        . '<br />Line: '
        . $e->getLine()
        . '</p>';
}
```

index then instantiates BootStrap, under '/framework/core', and passes the above array through the constructor which sets it in the class itself.

BootStrap then instantiates StartPage, under '/framework/web', and passes the paths array once again through the constructor.

StartPage then instantiates a class which sets the style-sheets, located under '/web/stylesheets', using the paths variable, like so:

```
class CssInclusion {

    private $paths;
    private $include_css;

    public function __construct($paths, $include_css) {

        // set variables
        $this->paths = $paths;
        $this->include_css = $include_css;
    }

    public function loadStylesheets() {

        // set path
        $directory_path = $this->paths['root'] . $this->paths['medium']. '/stylesheets';

        // loop through stylesheet array
        foreach ($this->include_css as $stylesheet) {

            // include stylesheet, handle exceptions
            $file_path = $directory_path . '/' .  $stylesheet . '.css';
            print_r($file_path);
            try {
                if (!is_file($file_path)) {
                    throw new Exception ('<b>Error - missing stylesheet:</b> ' . $file_path . '<br />');
                }
                echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $file_path . '" />';
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo
                    '<p><b>EXCEPTION</b><br />Message: '
                    . $e->getMessage()
                    . '<br />File: '
                    . $e->getFile()
                    . '<br />Line: '
                    . $e->getLine()
                    . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get an exception, yet the style-sheet doesn't load. It's very weird. Can your fresh eyes see what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root path is an absolute system path like `srv/www`.
But a stylesheet path has to be a relative or absolute path that is accessible by the browser.

`http://yoursite/css` or `/css`

I get my basePath like so:

```
$pathInfo = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$basePath = $pathInfo['dirname'];
```

Perhaps you only have to change that line:

```
$directory_path = $this->paths['medium']. '/stylesheets';
```

I don't know what `$this->paths['medium']` contains?!

Comment: I updated my post to show the full index script so you can see what it contains.. your solution didn't work. Instead, it broke the link to an include i have just a couple of lines down from where i set the array (and use it for the first time). See above..

Comment: Then reverse the root path and make another key `'base' => base_path,`. Then change the line `$directory_path = $this->paths['base'] . $this->paths['medium']. '/stylesheets';`

Comment: reverse the root path? sorry, can you please explain that? Not sure why I would add a new key with the same value as key 'root' either. can you please explain?

Comment: You are aware of that mixing PHP with HTML code is not the best pratice? I would try to output HTML code only in the template file or view script. You have heard of MVC for example. [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller).

Comment: I mean change the root path to what it was before: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Oh, you mean put it back to the way it was.. that's hackish.. i need to understand the problem.. not just work around it.. Why does $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] work from the array in the same file, but not from the same (passed on) array in a different file? Makes no sense.

Comment: You need the rootpath if you include php files and the basepath if you include stylesheets, javascript files, images etc. into the HTML output.

Comment: Also, I am not getting an exception. which means PHP is returned that it can find and read the file.. the browser is not interpreting it? Wrong headers maybe?

Comment: Right.. so wouldn't it just be easier to do this in the inclusion file?: $directory_path = '/' . $this->paths['medium']. '/stylesheets'; (Doesn't work by the way, AND that throws an exception)

Comment: Shure PHP can read it..but you cannot insert something like `srv/www/yoursite/stylesheet.css` into the browser. The browser has no access to your filesystem.

Comment: you're right.. but then why doesn't this work: $directory_path = '/' . $this->paths['medium']. '/stylesheets';

Comment: You can test it if you insert the output from `print_r($file_path)` into the browser. For example your site is `http://localhost/site` and the `print_r` returns `/web/stylesheets/mystyle.css` then put `http://localhost/site/web/stylesheets/mystyle.css` into the address bar. If the browser can find the stylesheet than it would work.

Comment: It worked. I added the key 'base' => 'rtrim($base_path, '/'), and now I use base for CSS/JS echo's and root to load php files. Thanks for your help!